# Get form values in hook_user_insert()

Tags: users, hooks

How can I get form values like first name, last name, email and password in `hook_user_insert()` in Drupal 8?

Comment: You can't, for this you would have to add a submit function in a form alter hook. But as the default submit has already run you'll find probably the values now inside of the entity.

Comment: Can you edit the question to give more information on what you wish to achieve. Then maybe you will get a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

The $account argument have the data that you like, but the password is protected.

It's not the best practice, but you can use reflection to get it:

```
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList $passObject */
$passObject = $account->get('pass');
/** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\PasswordItem $passItem */
$passItem = $passObject->get(0);
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($passItem);
$reflectionProperty = $reflection->getProperty('values');
// This do the magic.
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
$pass = $reflectionProperty->getValue($passItem)['value'];
```

See more about hook_user_insert [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.6.x).